# Pennsylvania State University system

Tags: word-usage

> To build on those earlier studies, the academies’ committee commissioned an analysis that found that 20% of female science students at the University of Texas’s campuses reported being sexually harassed by faculty members or staff there (see graphic). A similar survey of the **Pennsylvania State University system** concluded that 43% of graduate students experienced harassment.

Source:  [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05404-6)

I understand "system" here as "organizational structure". Am I on the right track?

Comment: State universities have many entities or other institutes related to them, which would come under that term structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to [the Pennsylvania State System of Higher Education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania_State_System_of_Higher_Education), which manages 14 state-owned universities and colleges in Pennsylvania.

*University system* means *a group of affiliated universities that are governed by one body* (in our case, by a state agency).

For more details:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_system
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania_State_System_of_Higher_Education